# Why are answered questions shown in the "unanswered" group?

Tags: discussion, bug

When I click on the "unanswered" link, the page shows several questions that have answers.  It also shows a question that was asked months ago about an event that was to happen in the beginning of October.  This makes the "unanswered" link rather useless.  Can it be fixed?

[image: page screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If the question has answers but all answers have a net score of zero (0) or below they are included in the unanswered tab.

As for the guy who went to Thailand last month, his question as applied to others who may have the same question still applies for those going in the future.

Comment: Yes, the tagline on the page says:  "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers"